# internet connection sharing after restart

Tags: internet, sharing

at wits end.   my comp uses wifi to connect to modem, I share this connection using ethernet to another router with several devices hooked to it. When i restart the system, i have to go to wifi properties to uncheck share and then recheck it in order to get the share working again. Is there a way to have this done automatically after a restart?> is there also a way to have a stable bridge between these units so the primary router gives IP instead of the standard 192.168,137.1. would love for it to pass along the connection so all my devices here will see the primary network. I have a nas hooked to the seconday network but want the primary to see it for backups. cant bridge my secondary to comcast modem as it freezes the modem after some use. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Hate to say it like this, but

You're using the wrong tool for the job. You would be better using a router that is designed to do that than use your PC.

[https://www.amazon.com/D-Link-Wireless-App-Enabled-Dual-Band-DIR-850L/dp/B00BYRPPAS/ref=sr_1_5?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1495662144&sr=1-5&keywords=dlink+ac](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BYRPPAS)

Something like this would work for you application.